# Spring не работает форма входа /login

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Я новичок в spring boot. Создаю свой сайт. Возникла проблема со входом в приложение. Перепробовал разные методы, не понимаю в чём проблема. При входе в http запросе появляется данный запрос http://localhost:8088/login?error и в форме выводит сообщение Invalid email and password. По бд запрос проходит и все нормально. Мне нужно чтобы после входа переводило на главную страницу, что я и пытался сделать.

UserService

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {

private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final PasswordConfig passwordConfig;
private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

@Autowired
public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordConfig passwordConfig, 
RoleRepository roleRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.passwordConfig = passwordConfig;
    this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    final Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    if(user.isPresent()) {
        return user.get();
    }else {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(MessageFormat.format("User with email {0} not found",email));
    }
}

@Override
public List<User> findAll() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}

public User findUserById(Long userId) {
    Optional<User> userFromDb = userRepository.findById(userId);
    return userFromDb.orElse(new User());
}

@Override
@Transactional
public boolean signUp(User user) {
    user.setPassword(passwordConfig.getPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
    user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(new Role(1L, "ROLE_USER")));
    userRepository.save(user);
    return true;
}
```

AuthenticationController

```
@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {

private final UserServiceImpl userService;

@Autowired
public AuthenticationController(UserServiceImpl userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@GetMapping("/registration")
public String registerPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "registration";
}

@PostMapping ("/registration")
public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult 
bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }
    userService.signUp(user);
    return "login";
}

@GetMapping("/login")
public String loginPage(){
      return "login";
}

@GetMapping("/logout")
public String logoutPage() throws Exception {
      return "redirect:/";
}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final UserServiceImpl userService;

private final PasswordConfig passwordConfig;

private final AuthenticationSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;

@Autowired
public WebSecurityConfig(UserServiceImpl userService, PasswordConfig passwordConfig, AuthenticationSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.passwordConfig = passwordConfig;
    this.authSuccessHandler = authSuccessHandler;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordConfig.getPasswordEncoder());
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordConfig.getPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**")
            .hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

login.html

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>SMS - Вход</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/home.css" 
th:href="@{/css/signup.css}">

</head>
<body>

<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="container has-text-centered has-text-info">
<h1>already logged in!</h1>
</div>

<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()" class="container">
<img th:src="@{/img/SMS.JPG}" class="logo" alt="">

<form action="/login" method="POST">

    <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="email" name="username" >
    <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" >
    <p th:if="${param.error}" class="has-text-danger">
        Invalid email and password.
    </p>

    <input type="checkbox" checked class="checkbox" id="terms-and-cond">
    <label for="terms-and-cond">agree to our <a href="">terms and conditions</a></label>
    <br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="notification">
        <label for="notification">recieve upcoming offers and events mails</a></label>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">sign in</button>
</form>
<a href="/registration" class="link">registr</a>
<a href="/" class="link">index</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

В консоле нет никаких ошибок, только:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.user_id as user_id1_8_, user0_.create_time as create_t2_8_, 
user0_.email as email3_8_, user0_.first_name as first_na4_8_, user0_.last_name as 
last_nam5_8_, user0_.password as password6_8_, user0_.phone_number as phone_nu7_8_ from user 
user0_ where user0_.email=?
```

Comment: Непонятна суть проблемы. Если в параметре url стоит error то выводит сообщение `Invalid email and password.` Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: @RomanC, извиняюсь если что, первый раз написал сюда вопрос. Постарался отредактировать вопрос чтобы более понятно было

Comment: Мне все равно ничего не понятно. Где у тебя происходит проверка пароля?

Comment: @RomanC объясните пожалуйста как она должна проходить. Возможно я что-то не понимаю, но все примеры которыми я пользовался при написании данного кода работают, а у меня нет.

Comment: Бесполезно объяснять, потому что не отвечаешь правильно на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: @RomanC аутентификация проводится в методе configure

Comment: нет, в конфиге только идёт настройка, скорее всего генерится неправильный SQL.

Comment: @RomanC спасибо за попытку помочь но я нашел свою ошибку. Я решил свою проблему просто добавив в сущность User поля enabled = true и locked = false. Я сначала добавлял свой класс юзера здесь чтобы все могли видеть однако позже удалил думая что захламляю все кодом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил свою проблему, мне помогло в класс сущности User добавить поля enabled = true,  locked = false

```
 @Builder.Default
 private Boolean locked = false;

 @Builder.Default
 private Boolean enabled = true;
```

Также не стоит забывать об имплементации интерфейса UserDetails c его методами